# width 100% for divs, table not working on mozilla and ie

Tags: html, flash

width 100% for divs, table not working on mozilla and ie. can anybody share their experience while working to achieve this. I wanted to place swf to occupy full web page

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on what you have tried, and in what way it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Flashcoder, care to share your code?

If its inline with another element you could try `<SPAN>`, but its hard to say without seeing your code.

Comment: Hi Rob, no specific code as such - what I did is inserted a table with 3 columns, i placed swf in middle column and made it 100% for height and width. width is ok, but height is taking 100px instead of %

Comment: Aaaaah, I see your problem now. I take it you have checked the table properties as well as the SWF properties?

Is the SWF set to 100px height?